# error: 'random_device' was not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, c++11, random, qt-creator

I tried fixing this :

> c++0x_warning.h:32: Fehler:#error This file requires compiler and
>   library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support
>   is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or
>   -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

by adding

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

to my .pro file.

Now I'm getting this error:

> error: 'random_device' was not declared in this scope
>        random_device rd;
>        ^

[image]

Comment: Your code seems inefficient. If you need good random numbers every time, then you don't need to use the random engine (mt19937), but this will be quite slow. It will be a lot faster if you only initialize the random engine once with the random_device and not on every call!

Comment: @typ1232 Thanks for pointing out.. How can I rectify it?
Should I make it global ? 
"random_device rd;
mt19937 mt(rd());"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you include the header:

```
#include <random>
```

and you may need to add std:: in front of random_device, unless you have mapped 'std' into your namespace using

```
using namespace std;
```

Note: It is generally preferable to explicitly specify std:: as opposed to mapping namespaces into your default namespace.

Comment: had forgotten namespace std.. Thank you loads!